# Disable double finger zoom after reaching maximum zoom

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I had allowed double finger map zoom on mobile devices which is good. 
But if maximum zoom level is reached I can zoom more, and when I release fingers from display map zoom is reverted to the max zoom level.

How can I disable further zoom in on mobile devices after max zoom level on the map is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of RTFM. If you look carefully at the [Leaflet API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-bounceatzoomlimits), you'll find the `bounceAtZoomLimits` option for `L.Map`. Let me quote:

> `bounceAtZoomLimits`  `Boolean`   default `true`
>
> Set it to `false` if you don't want the map to zoom beyond min/max zoom and then bounce back when pinch-zooming.

so:

```
var mymap = L.map('map', {
    bounceAtZoomLimits: false
})
```